# Extract first characters from list series pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, character

I have a string series containing multiples words. I want to extract the first character of each word per row in a vectorized fashion.

So far, I have been able to split the words into a list, but haven't found a vectorized way of getting the first characters.

```
s = pd.Series(['aa bb cc', 'cc dd ee', 'ff ga', '0w'])

>>> s. str.split()
0    [aa, bb, cc]
1    [cc, dd, ee]
2        [ff, ga]
3            [0w]
```

Eventually, I want something like this:

```
0    [a, b, c]
1    [c, d, e]
2       [f, g]
3          [0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another faster solution is nested list comprehension:

```
s2 = pd.Series([[y[0] for y in x.split()] for x in s.tolist()])
print (s2)
0    [a, b, c]
1    [c, d, e]
2       [f, g]
3          [0]
dtype: object
```

Thank you [clocker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935729/extract-first-characters-from-list-series-pandas/37936260#comment63326032_37936260) for improvement - you can remove `tolist()`:

```
print (pd.Series([[y[0] for y in x.split()] for x in s]))
```

**Timings**:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['aa bb cc', 'cc dd ee', 'ff ga', '0w'])
s = pd.concat([s]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
print(s)

In [42]: %timeit pd.Series([[y[0] for y in x.split()] for x in s.tolist()])
10 loops, best of 3: 28.6 ms per loop

In [43]: %timeit (s.str.split().map(lambda lst : [string[0] for string  in lst]))
10 loops, best of 3: 50.4 ms per loop

In [44]: %timeit (s.str.split().apply(lambda lst: [list(elt)[0] for elt in lst]))
10 loops, best of 3: 76.1 ms per loop

In [59]: %timeit (pd.Series([[y[0] for y in x.split()] for x in s]))
10 loops, best of 3: 28.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for considering efficiency.

Comment: The answer from "jezrael" is a good one. Just want to add that for list comprehension, iterating over a sequence such as a Series does not require the .tolist() method. Minor point for small amounts of data but can add up for large Series. `pd.Series([[y[0] for y in x.split()] for x in s])` will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way would be to use the `pandas.Series.map` method:

```
In [15]: s.str.split().map(lambda lst : [string[0] for string  in lst])
Out[15]: 
0    [a, b, c]
1    [c, d, e]
2       [f, g]
3          [0]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think about using map. Think I'll use it more extensively for these type of operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
>>> s2 = s.str.split()
>>> s2.apply(lambda lst: [list(elt)[0] for elt in lst])
0    [a, b, c]
1    [c, d, e]
2       [f, g]
3          [0]
```

Hope it'll be helpful.